# Am I changing directories properly in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to compile a github project with Python. I imported my os, but I am getting a syntax error when I attempt to change directories with this code:     `os.chdir(C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder)`

After doing that, I get this:

```
    >>> os.chdir(C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.chdir(C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I see that it is pointing at the colon. Am I putting in the directory incorrectly? (I have never used python in my life.) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try making your path a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it a string. And because it's a Windows path, it should be a raw string (Quote mark prefixed with `r`, like `r''`), so the backslashes don't get interpreted as string literal escapes (raw strings are more succinct than the alternative of doubling all the backslashes), making it:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder')
```

Comment: Good answer. Forward slashes also work on Windows (they have worked since Dos 2.0 added directories, but that doesn't seem to be well known).

Comment: @cco: Yar. Forward slashes on Windows just seem non-idiomatic to me, so I tend to encourage using raw strings to produce readable/correct path strings. It's a good thing to note though.

Comment: That's why I upvoted your answer.  I just thought this was a good place to leave a note other people might see, so they can know too.